# In Aristotelian virtue ethics, what is the virtue-vice-vice pattern for obtuseness?

Tags: aristotle, virtue-ethics

From Albert Einstein:

> All this occurs quietly and demurely. Even the children are spiritless and look obtuse.

(Source: ["The Travel Diaries of Albert Einstein"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691174419/the-travel-diaries-of-albert-einstein))

In Aristotelian virtue ethics, virtues are the mean between two extreme vices. Courage is the virtue in between the two vices of cowardice and foolhardiness. Modesty is the virtue in between the two vices of lasciviousness and prudishness. Truthfulness (accuracy) is the virtue in between the two vices of gullibility (type 1 error) and cynicism (type 2 error).

There is some triplet of virtue-vice-vice that obtuseness belongs to, so that the sentence "A is the virtue in between the two vices of B and obtuseness" is true.

What are A and B?

Comment: I believe that the virtues and vices are defined and set. I don't think obtuseness is included in the standard set of virtues and vices given by Aristotle.